# add multi select dropdown selected values to sharepoint list by Ecmascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have a sharepoint list which where I want to insert multi selected values from a dropdown list.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
   <option>A</option>
   <option>B</option>
....
</select>
```

My question is can anyone show a sample code/idea how can I achieve it by using ecmascript?

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 types of selection based columns:

1. Choice lists (single value and multi-value)
2. Lookup lists
3. Managed Metadata
4. Custom multi-valued columns - most complex - won't fit really as it is too complex.

There is a difference in how you would need to read/store these values. For example for Lookup you would use `SP.FieldLookupValue` which shall return an array, as in

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) 
    {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    var selItems = oListItem.get_item('SelectedItems');
    var i=0;
      for(i=0;i<selItems.length;i++)
      {
        alert(selItems[i].get_lookupValue());
       }
    }
}
```

See [here](http://kamilmka.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/ecmascript-client-object-model-get-the-values-from-a-multi-select-lookup-column-field/) a full example